# Opensource Bluetooth JAVA API

Tags: java, linux, bluetooth, fedora

I'm trying to build a very simple application that fetches all the discovered Bluetooth devices and do something with it. I looked around for some APIs to get started with, but the only one I could find was BlueCove. I tried using it, but it ended up having tons of issues. Majorly: `com.intel.bluetooth.BluetoothStackBlueZ not available`

I use `Linux Fedora 20, JDK 1.7 and Intellij IDE`. Can anyone suggest a reliable `opensource` Bluetooth Java API, that works properly on a linux environment and also has some appreciable documentation/tutorials?

Comment: did you add the bluecove-gpl jar to your classpath ?

Comment: Stupid of me. I was unaware that I should add such a library. Anyway, I did. And now it works. However, back to my question, are there any other APIs than this?